# Grafana / Elasticsearch datasource / Count values with no group by clause

Tags: elasticsearch, grafana, elasticsearch-aggregation

With elasticsearch datasource, I would like to populate a stats widget with the count of records corresponding to a query.
It seems it's mandatory to provide a group by field with the count option and I don't see the value_count function.
I found it's possible to use transformations to calculate the total of records, but is there a better way to achieve that since value_count in elasticsearch gives me the result I expect ?

Thanks